# How can I convert jQuery's $.get to pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery:

```
$.get( "someurl", function( data ) {
  alert( data );
});
```

How to turn this into pure JavaScript?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: First port of call for questions like this: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com. In fact, the answer to your question is in the first section.

Comment: .get is shorthand for .ajax. Which hides a LOT of the complexity of AJAX. I used to use AJAX directly in Javascript years ago, and once I found how easy it is to use jQuery I haven't looked back. If the issue is getting the jQuery via CDN (e.g., on a locked-down network), you can host it yourself. Why wouldn't you want to use jQuery?

Comment: @manassehkatz: Why *would* he want it? There's just no need for it today.

Comment: Overhead and not depending on external code in proprietary apps.

Comment: @manassehkatz: As with anything, it's a tradeoff - if your site uses it for tons of DOM manipulation and AJAX and utilities etc, then sure, it's great. If all you're using it for is one thing, then it's a pretty chunky dependency for not a lot of gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XMLHttpRequest,

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {         
         // handle xhr.response
    }
}
xhr.send();
```